safe UI cant find cfg chain and currency logo
I am using
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/
tried a solution here
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/issues/149
nginx docker component and config:
    rewrite ^(/(media)(/.*)?)$ /cfg$1 last;
    
    location /cfg/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        add_header              Front-End-Https   on;
        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://cfg_app_server/;

        # They default to 60s. Increase to avoid WORKER TIMEOUT in web container
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
  }

cfg.env:
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME=/cfg/

CGW_URL=http://nginx:8000/cgw
CGW_FLUSH_TOKEN=some_random_token

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS="http://some_nginx_ip:8000"

MEDIA_URL=/media/
MEDIA_ROOT=/app/media

when accessing the ui:

inside the cfg-web container:
# find / -name chain_logo.png 2>/dev/null
/app/src/media/chains/530/chain_logo.png

might be relevant docker-compose.yml:
volumes:
  nginx-shared-txs:
  nginx-shared-fxcore-txs:
  nginx-shared-cfg:

services:
  # Common nginx and database
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "${REVERSE_PROXY_PORT}:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:rw
      - nginx-shared-txs:/nginx-txs
      - nginx-shared-fxcore-txs:/nginx-fxcore-txs
      - nginx-shared-cfg:/nginx-cfg
    depends_on:
      - txs-web
      - fxcore-txs-web
      - cfg-web
      - cgw-web
      - events-web

  # Safe Config Service
  cfg-web:
    image: safeglobal/safe-config-service:${CFG_VERSION}
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - nginx-shared-cfg:/nginx
    env_file:
      - container_env_files/cfg.env
    depends_on:
      cfg-db:
        condition: service_healthy

Accessing the logo directly work:

